# How to limit copying from electron app to certain word length?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have an electron app with some data which I want to protect from being copied. I'm aware that there can't be 100% safety but the users will be not be techies, so a simple solution will do it.

What I have already done:
- Disabling select via CSS. `user-select: none;`

Problem here: Even if the selection is invisible it's still possible to copy all the content.

Clearing the clipboard on <kbd>CTRL / CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> via:

```
globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+C', () => {
    clipboard.clear();
});
```

Problem here: The handler seems indeed to be global, I'ts funny running this and trying to copy/paste in VisualCode ;)
Would be cool to have it ONLY in one app.

Plus: Would be cool to still allow copying for short strings. If anybody has an idea how to access e.g. the current selection in the globalShortcut*, I could set this truncated to 300 chars to the clipboard.

*`window` is undefined

Comment: *"Problem here: The handler seems indeed to be global, I'ts funny running this and trying to copy/paste in VisualCode ;)"* Um....if *your* Electron app doing that affects *other* Electron apps running on the same machine, that's a big fat hairy bug that needs reporting and fixing quick.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it seems to be the intended behaviour https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/global-shortcut.md

Comment: I read that, and I don't think it is, or at least it's not clear that it is from that documentation. Just because the handler is registered with the OS, that doesn't mean your app should affect other apps. In any case, you're looking to handle the case where you *do* have keyboard focus, right? Surely there's some other API point for that?

Comment: I get the point, but we are apparently not the first thinking this is buggy ;) https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8491 - so I'll give the in the issue mentioned `electron-localshortcut` a try.
Edit: or just RTFM https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/keyboard-shortcuts ;)

Answer (score 1):

I ditched the whole global/local shortcut thing and made use of the copy event. Seems to work fine til now.

```
['copy', 'cut'].forEach((eventName) => {
    document.addEventListener(eventName, (e) => {
        const selection = window.getSelection().toString();
        const truncatedSelection = selection.slice(0, 300);

        if (selection.length > 299) {
            alert('Selection to huge. Please select less.');
        }

        e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', truncatedSelection);
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/html', truncatedSelection);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```